# ReflectionException in Container.php line 734: Class PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am installing Laravel Stats Tracker in laravel 5.2, and add my providers and facades, set my middleware files, kernel.php and config / database.php file.

Migration run my console, but in my browser I have the following error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker does not exist
```

These are my providers:

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

        /*
        *
        */

        PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

These are my aliases:

```
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

        'Tracker' => PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Facade::class,

    ],
```

This my Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Middlewares\Tracker::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

This my tracker.php file in app/config/

```
<?php

return [

    /**
     * Enable it?
     */
    'enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Deffer booting for middleware use
     */
    'use_middleware' => true,

    /**
     * Robots should be tracked?
     */
    'do_not_track_robots' => false,

    /**
     * Which environments are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_environments' => [
        // defaults to none
    ],

    /**
     * Which routes names are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_routes' => [
        'tracker.stats.*',
    ],

    /**
     * The Do Not Track Ips is used to disable Tracker for some IP addresses:
     *
     *     '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.1'
     *
     * You can set ranges of IPs
     *     '192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100'
     *
     * And use net masks
     *     '10.0.0.0/32'
     *     '172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0'
     */
    'do_not_track_ips' => [
        '127.0.0.0/24' /// range 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.255
    ],

    /**
     * Log every single access?
     *
     * The log table can become huge if your site is popular, but...
     *
     * Log table is also responsible for storing information on:
     *
     *    - Routes and controller actions accessed
     *    - HTTP method used (GET, POST...)
     *    - Error log
     *    - URL queries (including values)
     */
    'log_enabled' => false,

    /**
     * Log SQL queries?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries' => false,

    /**
     * If you prefer to store Tracker data on a different database or connection,
     * you can set it here.
     *
     * To avoid SQL queries log recursion, create a different connection for Tracker,
     * point it to the same database (or not) and forbid logging of this connection in
     * do_not_log_sql_queries_connections.
     */
    'connection' => 'tracker',

    /**
     * Forbid logging of SQL queries for some connections.
     *
     * To avoid recursion, you better ignore Tracker connection here.
     *
     * Please create a separate database connection for Tracker. It can hit
     * the same database of your application, but the connection itself
     * has to have a different name, so the package can ignore its own queries
     * and avoid recursion.
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_sql_queries_connections' => [
        'tracker'
    ],

    /**
     * Also log SQL query bindings?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries_bindings' => false,

    /**
     * Log events?
     */
    'log_events' => false,

    /**
     * Which events do you want to log exactly?
     */
    'log_only_events' => [
        // defaults to logging all events
    ],

    /**
     * What are the names of the id columns on your system?
     *
     * 'id' is the most common, but if you have one or more different,
     * please add them here in your preference order.
     */
    'id_columns_names' => [
        'id'
    ],
    /**
     * Do not log events for the following patterns.
     * Strings accepts wildcards:
     *
     *    eloquent.*
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_events' => [
        'illuminate.log',
        'eloquent.*',
        'router.*',
        'composing: *',
        'creating: *',
    ],

    /**
     * Do you wish to log Geo IP data?
     *
     * You will need to install the geoip package
     *
     *     composer require "geoip/geoip":"~1.14"
     *
     * And remove the PHP module
     *
     *     sudo apt-get purge php5-geoip
     *
     */
    'log_geoip' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log the user agent?
     */
    'log_user_agents' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log your users?
     */
    'log_users' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log devices?
     */
    'log_devices' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log HTTP referers?
     */
    'log_referers' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log url paths?
     */
    'log_paths' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log url queries and query arguments?
     */
    'log_queries' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log routes and route parameters?
     */
    'log_routes' => false,

    /**
     * Log errors and exceptions?
     */
    'log_exceptions' => false,

    /**
     * A cookie may be created on your visitor device, so you can have information
     * on everything made using that device on your site.    *
     */
    'store_cookie_tracker' => false,

    /**
     * If you are storing cookies, you better change it to a name you of your own.
     */
    'tracker_cookie_name' => 'please_change_this_cookie_name',

    /**
     * Internal tracker session name.
     */
    'tracker_session_name' => 'tracker_session',

    /**
     * ** IMPORTANT **
     *   Change the user model to your own.
     */
    'user_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\User',

    /**
     * You can use your own model for every single table Tracker has.
     */

    'session_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Session',

    'log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Log',

    'path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Path',

    'query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Query',

    'query_argument_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\QueryArgument',

    'agent_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Agent',

    'device_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Device',

    'cookie_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Cookie',

    'domain_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Domain',

    'referer_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Referer',

    'referer_search_term_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RefererSearchTerm',

    'route_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Route',

    'route_path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePath',

    'route_path_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePathParameter',

    'error_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Error',

    'geoip_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\GeoIp',

    'sql_query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQuery',

    'sql_query_binding_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBinding',

    'sql_query_binding_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBindingParameter',

    'sql_query_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryLog',

    'connection_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Connection',

    'event_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Event',

    'event_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\EventLog',

    'system_class_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SystemClass',

    /**
     * Laravel internal variables on user authentication and login.
     */
    'authentication_ioc_binding' => 'auth', // defaults to 'auth' in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

    'authenticated_check_method' => 'check', // to Auth::check()

    'authenticated_user_method' => 'user', // to Auth::user()

    'authenticated_user_id_column' => 'id', // to Auth::user()->id

    'authenticated_user_username_column' => 'email', // to Auth::user()->email

    /**
     * Enable the Stats Panel?
     */
    'stats_panel_enabled' => false,

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes before filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_before_filter' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes after filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_after_filter' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes middleware
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_middleware' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel template path
     */
    'stats_template_path' => '/templates/sb-admin-2',

    /**
     * Stats Panel base uri.
     *
     * If your site url is http://wwww.mysite.com, then your stats page will be:
     *
     *    http://wwww.mysite.com/stats
     *
     */
    'stats_base_uri' => 'stats',

    /**
     * Stats Panel layout view
     */
    'stats_layout' => 'pragmarx/tracker::layout',

    /**
     * Stats Panel controllers namespace
     */
    'stats_controllers_namespace' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Controllers',
];
```

After the configuration of these files, I run the migration of my tables, that process was executed without errors.

But in the browser it generates the initial error.

Error stack:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jr5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht8Ay.jpg)

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace ?

Comment: Thank you jaysingkar, I modify the post and place the configuration files.

Comment: by stack trace I meant the complete page where the error is shown, it will point out at which controller you are getting this error

Comment: Ok, sorry i post a image.

Comment: @EdwardPalen Can you check to confirm that in your vendor directory that `pragmarx/tracker/src/Vendor/Laravel/Middlewares/tracker.php` really exists?

Comment: Hello @OluwafemiSule, the file is not in the directory, i create Tracker.‌​php file with the same parameters as the TrackVisitsMiddleware.php file, the problem was corrected.

I assume that this error may occur when installing in laravel version 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file Tracker.‌​php is not in the directory, i create a file with the same parameters as the TrackVisitsMiddleware.php file, the problem was corrected. I assume that this error may occur when installing in laravel version 5.2.